# "so, if you know any schools looking for a physics teacher, I'm down.", the meaning of "I'm down"

Tags: adjectives

A Candian friend said this to me today:

> so, if you know any schools looking for a physics teacher, I'm down.

What does "I'm down" mean here? Apparently it doesn't mean "I am upset".

An English teacher told me that it means "I will join in".

Could anyone explain it and tell me which entry (a link is much appreicated) in dictionary fit this meaning? Because I tried Oxford dictionary, Collions and Merriam Webster, I couldn't find related entry. Thanks

Comment: I think this question might be qualified here while I can go ell stackexchange..

Comment: I suspect that the "down" in "I'm down" comes from "to have one's name down for something". This comes from, e.g. "If you want to go on the school trip put your name **down** on the list." Thus "I'm down" = "My name is down (on the list) = I am willing/I wish to do this, etc."

Comment: @Greybeard Very interesting, thanks for telling me that :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's slang. Because it's slang, [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=down) is a relevant resource.

> 1. To be 'With It or in 'the know how', knowledgeable about something, or to give respect/recognition to something.
> 2. To be keen for something.

While (1) doesn't fit, (2) does.

> so, if you know any schools looking for a physics teacher, I'm keen; I'm eager.

A synonymous usage would be "I'm up for it"; slang often develops by (mis-)using words with a meaning opposite to their customary meaning.

> 4. *informal* Ready to take part in (a particular activity)
>
> [Oxford via Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/up_for)

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know Urban Dictionary is a slang dictionary :(. Now I know.